# Pjax animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slide, pjax

I finally got pjax working, but I have another question.. How do I add some jquery animation like fadeout/slideup old content and fadein/slidedown new content?

By default pjax just changes the content without any good looking effects..

Any help would be much appreciated.

Best Regards

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basically, you have [a bunch of events](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#events) to latch on to and do as you like. Here's a basic `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` version using the  `pjax:start` and `pjax:end` as triggers.

```
$(document)
  .on('pjax:start', function() { $('#main').fadeOut(200); })
  .on('pjax:end',   function() { $('#main').fadeIn(200); })
```

Obviously you would swap `#main` for the container element you're swapping content in and out of.

Comment: It is not working in my site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464641/pjax-add-animation-to-content . Please help

Comment: u can have better result by changing the `pjax:end` to `pjax:complete` and have different timing for the fadeIn & out to avoid the content flickering.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you want to create a directory browser, just like GitHub.

Let's start with Twitter Bootstrap's carousel and create a view with markup to use it (hope you don't mind haml):

Here's the container:

```
%div#uber-glider.glider.carousel.span12
  %div.carousel-inner
    = yield
%div#uber-glider-stage.glider-stage(style="display:none")
```

And here's a sample partial to render the pjaxed content within it:

```
%div.glider-group.item
  %div.glider-heading(data-title="#{@super_department.name} Super Department" data-resource="#{super_department_path @super_department.id}")
    %ul.breadcrumb
      %li
        %a.glider-link(href="#{divisions_path}")= "Divisions"
        %span.divider= "/"
      %li.active
        %a.glider-link(href="#{division_path @division.id}")= @division.name
        %span.divider= "/"
      %li.active
        = @super_department.name
  %div.glider-body
    - @super_department.departments.each_with_index do |department, i|
      %div.glider-listing
        %a.glider-link(data-glide="descend" data-target="#uber-glider" href="#{department_path department.id}")
          = department.name
```

Now let's create some Javascript with pjax:

```
(function($){
    "use strict";

  $(function() {
    $('#uber-glider-stage').on('pjax:success', function(e){
      var $incoming_group = $('#uber-glider-stage .glider-group')
        , $incoming_heading = $('#uber-glider-stage .glider-heading')
        , incoming_resource = $incoming_heading.data('resource')
        , $existing_groups = $('#uber-glider .glider-group')
        , $existing_headings = $('#uber-glider .glider-heading')
        , existing_last_idx = $existing_groups.length - 1
        , matching_idx = -1;
      $existing_headings.each(function(idx) {
        if ($(this).data('resource') === incoming_resource) {
          matching_idx = idx;
        }
      });
      if (matching_idx > -1) {
        // pop                        
        $incoming_group.remove();
        $('#uber-glider').one('slid', function() {
          for (; existing_last_idx > matching_idx; existing_last_idx--) {
            $('#uber-glider .glider-group').last().remove();
          }
        });
        $('#uber-glider').carousel(matching_idx);
      }
      else {
        // push        
        debug.debug("pushing 1 level");
        $incoming_group.detach();
        var $container = $('#uber-glider > .carousel-inner');
        $container.append($incoming_group);
        $('#uber-glider').carousel('next');
      }
    });


    $('.glider-link').pjax('#uber-glider-stage', { 'timeout' : '3000' }).on('click', function(){
      debug.debug(".glider-link click");
    });
  });

  $('#uber-glider .carousel-inner .item').addClass('active');
  $('#uber-glider').carousel('pause');
})(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: You don't need to use `%div.cssClass` for <div>s in HAML, just use `.cssClass` (default tag is DIV :) )

Answer (score 1):

I guess that a loading indicator and an animation are more or less the same thing. In that case, use pjax:send and pjax:complete events.

From [pjax readme](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax),

> send and complete are a good pair of events to use if you are
>   implementing a loading indicator. They'll only be triggered if an
>   actual request is made, not if it's loaded from cache.