# Pjax: add animation to content

Tags: jquery, animation, pjax

For my website i used pjax. I wants to add fadeout and fadein animations to pages.

I tried [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581849/pjax-animations)

My code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// invoke pjax
        $(function(){           
          $('div#header-menu a').pjax('#master-div')            
        })
// do animation
  $(document).on('pjax:start', function() { $('#content').fadeOut(1000); })
  $(document).on('pjax:end',   function() { $('#content').fadeIn(1000);})
    </script>
```

'content' is the id of div that keeps changing on pjax

Am i doing something wrong?

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: Please post more code, it's hard to tell what is wrong from the limited code excerpt you have posted. You can use [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to post a more complete example of what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

may be you need to close  " }) "

```
  .on('pjax:start', function() { $('#main').fadeOut(200); })
  .on('pjax:end',   function() { $('#main').fadeIn(200); **})**
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake i already have that with my code. It happened when coping pasting here

Comment: Is there anything else that i could have done wrong? Please help. I have been trying this for hours

Answer (score 0):

Does tweaking your JS a little like this help any?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){           
    // invoke pjax
    $('div#header-menu a').pjax('#content')            
    // do animation
    $(document).on('pjax:start', function() { $('#content').fadeOut(1000); })
    $(document).on('pjax:end',   function() { $('#content').fadeIn(1000);})
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Please help. I am tearing my hair out